# Viewport height in mobile changes

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, viewport

Ok, this isn't a new problem. I see a few people here have asked about it but I'm hoping maybe someone has a new answer. It seems like this should be a more common issue.

When an element's height is set to 100vh (100% of the viewport height), it works fine. However, if you scroll down (at least on Android) the address bar goes away and changes the viewport height. This suddenly shifts the page as the 100vh height changes.

The solutions I have seen involve javascript. This might not really be a problem in my particular case but I am hoping maybe there is some CSS solution to this.

Comment: Don't remember where I've read it, but somebody opened several bug reports on this in chrome and iOS dev platforms and the only response was that this is fully intentional and not to be changed any time soon. I know this behaviour very well and hate it just as much. I gave up on trying to get around it and live with it, trying to adapt my design as much as possible. I think its good UI but the redimensioning in pixels is an issue in my opinion. I don't think there's any pure CSS workaround yet (I'd better be wrong), as I was just recently searching myself. Kudos and hopes for the future!